# WinRT Replacement of System.Environment.TickCount

Tags: c#, timer, windows-8, windows-runtime

What is the WinRT replacement for System.Environment.TickCount?

Comment: What do you need it for? For many uses `DateTime.UtcNow` is perfectly fine, but it's not equivalent.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow is not a replacement if you need monotonic time. UtcNow is an arbitrary value.

Comment: TickCount is an arbitrary value as well.  DateTime.UtcNow.Tick is monotonic.

Comment: @Hans Passant, UtcNow can jump backwars if the user adjust the time back. Env.TickCount is monotonic. This issue actually caused a bug in the timeout implementation of ManualResetEventSlim which I reported and which was fixed. When the user changed the clock time the timeout elapsed suddenly or never elapsed.

Comment: Hmm, this normally requires an explicit call to  CultureInfo.ClearCachedData.  Glad that the bug was fixed :)

Comment: System.Environment.TickCount is included in the subset of the .Net framework available to .Net windows store projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be available, because it [isn't a problem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205762.aspx).  But it is not, a [TypeForwardedTo] hangup I guess because GetTickCount() isn't on the white list and .NET never adopted GetTickCount64.  The standard fallback works fine, you can use pinvoke the call the native Windows function.  I verified that a program that uses it passes the Windows App Certification Kit test.

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern long GetTickCount64();
```

Note that it returns a long, not an int.  You can simply cast to int to truncate if that's important in C# (but not vb.net, just lie about the return type)

Comment: So I am confused. If they are allowed for Metro Apps, then why is it not present in the C# APIs by default?

Comment: I tried to explain it in the answer.  Don't shoot the messenger, I prefer answers that solve a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I didn't mean to harp on you. I wonder if this will change with the final release. Thanks though.

Comment: BEWARE, this code will make your WinRT application not run on ARM

Answer (score 1):

It appears System.Environment.TickCount is supported in Windows 8 Windows store apps now.